# CypressError: `cy.setCookie()` must be passed two string arguments for `name` and `value` when trying to set cookies using environment variables

Tags: cypress

I am trying to write a script to run my test suite once on every server node our client has running, using AWS cookies to target each server.

I'm able to spin up a server and get the cookie I need, and then am execute a command to run the tests:
`CYPRESS_BASE_URL=${website_url} npx cypress run --env AWSALB_COOKIE_VALUE=${awsAlbCookieValueString}`

I *do* have code that converts the cookie to a string even though I think it already is one.

I have the below `beforeEach` method to set the cookie before each test:

```
beforeEach(function setCookies() {
    cy.setCookie('AWSALB', Cypress.env('AWSALB_COOKIE_VALUE'));
})
```

All my tests are failing with the error message: "CypressError: `cy.setCookie()` must be passed two string arguments for `name` and `value`"

Is this a limitation of the framework that the value needs to be a raw string, and not something like an environment variable that is a string?

I also tried export/importing the cookie value from my script to the file where my `beforeEach` method lives and got errors about an "unexpected" token export.

Answer (score 1):

First, verify that the value of AWSALB_COOKIE_VALUE is present and being passed through from the environment to Cypress.  The error message indicates the value might not be present.

One suggestion for importing this environment variable would be to set the environment variable in the Cypress Plugins config (`cypress/plugins/index.js`)

```
export default (on, config) => {
  config.env.AWSALB_COOKIE_VALUE = process.env.AWSALB_COOKIE_VALUE;
  return config
}
```

This pattern can be seen in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/)  -
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/plugins/index.ts#L10